# .htaccess rewriterule giving a 500 error

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using virtual subdomains to catch all traffic to my site and using the subdomain as an identifier in an app. All traffic to a non-subdomain URL should use index.html; but I'm not having any luck getting the redirect to send subdomain traffic to the correct page. So far I've got:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /var/sites/w/domain.org/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub.html
```

The index page loads on a domain URL, but a subdomain URL gets a 500 error, instead of redirecting to http://sub.domain.org/sub.html (note, it's important that I keep the subdomain in the redirected URL).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try including a condition to check if the URI is *already* `/sub.html`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^sub\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub.html
```